# Data from Dockerfile RUN step not in image

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I'm setting up a MongoDB container to run software integration tests against and I want to have the docker file add the test user to the database so that the tests can log in and execute their steps. I want to be able to capture all of the steps in the `Dockerfile` so I'm trying to avoid starting the container, manually adding the users, and then recapturing the image.

To that end, I've created this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:3.2.0
COPY add_user.sh /
RUN /add_user.sh
```

and `add_user.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod &

RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    sleep 1
    mongo admin --eval "help" >/dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done

echo "Adding testUser..."
mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user:'testUser',pwd:'P@ssw0rd',roles:['readWrite']})"

echo "User added"
mongo admin --eval "db.getUsers()"

mongod --shutdown
```

While the image is building, I can see that the user has been successfully added, but when I run the image then the database in the container does not contain any users.

Why isn't the user being captured in the image? How can I add a user during the image build process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the mongo image uses a `VOLUME` for the data directory, which makes docker store the database data *outside* of the image, and that data is not persisted in the image (see the Dockerfile for the mongo:3.2 image; https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fcb9584617e63f1d3db8dc730fb8abb83653c7ad/3.2/Dockerfile#L54)

So, even though the command has run successfully, the database itself is stored outside of the image.

In docker, volumes are used so that the data is persisted independently of a container's lifecycle (i.e., you can destroy a container, but the data inside the volume is kept around, so that you can start a new container, using the same volume/data)

Downsides are, that a you cannot "bake" the data in an image if the Dockerfile uses a `VOLUME` declaration.

For some discussions around this, see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18287, and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3465

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. So if I'm understanding the `VOLUME` command correctly, since my parent image contains `VOLUME /data/db` then everything written to /data/db during image building will be thrown out. It sounds like if I ditch the `FROM mongo` and instead use the `mongo` Dockerfile, minus the `VOLUME /data/db/` command, then I should be able to pre-populate the database during building and have it persist in the container, at the cost of not being able to mount the /data/db/ volume outside of the container. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Alternatively, configure mongodb to use a different directory for its data, so that it's not inside the `VOLUME` path during build, Then, when starting a container from it, make sure you `-v /your/custom/data-path`, so that the data is copied to a volume. Using a volume is best practice, also w.r.t. Performance